# Extending Blogpost Contenttype in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Has anybody ever used blogpost contenttype and extended it and added some column to it. I know we can add columns to it using the GUI (List Setting).

Can we do this declaratively and add it to the portal using feature, so that we can create a deployable solution.

Paddy

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't. The only thing that gives me pause is that Blogs are a little different than most lists because the List Definition is not in a Feature but is rather part of the Site Definition. You could create a Feature with your custom Content Type and staple it to BLOG#1. However, you will still need something (probably a Feature Receiver) that will modify the instance of the Posts lists by adding your custom columns and associating your custom Content Type.